# Decode eth_call response without a given ABI

Tags: ethereum, polygon, ethers.js

My task is to call a view function from a contract, deployed on the Polygon network, using only the hexadecimal selector of the function. I did that through an eth_call. The response I get is the following: `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`

How do I decode this response, considering, that no ABI is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html):

> The encoding is not self describing and thus requires a schema in order to decode.

So it's impossible to decode this ABI with 100% certainty. However, given the context **we are able to make an educated guess** about the ABI schema.

To illustrate, break up the response into 32 byte segments (offset labels are provided for ease of reading):

```
000: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
020: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000cf
040: 43616c6c207468697320636f6e747261637420776974682066756e6374696f6e
060: 207369676e6174757265202730786464633234626533272070726f766964696e
080: 672061202775696e743235362720617267756d656e74206f662076616c75653a
0a0: 2032323738313739373039323836383136393238383732353634343138343332
0c0: 3338313336303133363830363431383135313932383334363635383039363531
0e0: 373931303039303331383138383720416c736f2073656e6420736f6d65207765
100: 693a203432303030303030303030300000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Looking at the data presented this way, this ABI is almost certainly encoding a `string` type:

- Slot `000` appears to be a pointer to slot `020`.
- Slot `020` appears to contain the length of the data (`0xcf == 207`).
- The 207 bytes starting from slot `040` and ending midway in slot `100` are legible English when UTF-8 decoded.

You can decode the 207 bytes in JavaScript like so:

```js
const str = '43616c6c207468697320636f6e747261637420776974682066756e6374696f6e207369676e6174757265202730786464633234626533272070726f766964696e672061202775696e743235362720617267756d656e74206f662076616c75653a20323237383137393730393238363831363932383837323536343431383433323338313336303133363830363431383135313932383334363635383039363531373931303039303331383138383720416c736f2073656e6420736f6d65207765693a20343230303030303030303030';
new TextDecoder().decode(Uint8Array.from(str.match(/.{2}/g), v => parseInt(v, 16)));
```

The result of the above code:

> "Call this contract with function signature '0xddc24be3' providing a 'uint256' argument of value: 22781797092868169288725644184323813601368064181519283466580965179100903181887 Also send some wei: 420000000000"